# Firestore and express, .then chain not stopping when returned res.status(401).json()

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, google-cloud-firestore

So, I'm trying to implement .increment into my API. I need to update a like count more than once per second so that's why I'm trying to update my API to do this. This is the exact code I'm trying to implement:

```
const postRef = db
      .collection('posts')
      .doc(postId);
postRef.update({likeCount: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)});
```

The code above works perfectly when there is no current like document associated to a user handle, but when there is, the

```
return res.status(401).json({'Error': `${req.user.userHandle} already liked this post`});
```

gets hit and returns the error message perfectly. But, the rest of the .then chains get hit, which they shouldn't be.

Here is the old code that works:

```
exports.likepost = (req, res) => {

    const postId = req.body.postId;

    db
        .collection('posts')
        .doc(postId)
        .get()
        .then((doc) => {
            if(!doc.exists){
                return res.status(404).json({'Error': `post ID ${postId} not found`});
            }
            else{
                return db.collection('likes')
                    .where('postId', '==', postId)
                    .where('userHandle', '==', req.user.userHandle)
                    .get();
            }
        })
        .then((likeDoc) => {
            if(!likeDoc.empty){
                return res.status(404).json({'Error': `${req.user.userHandle} already liked this post`});
            }
            else{
                return db
                    .collection('posts')
                    .doc(postId)
                    .get()
            }
        })
        .then((doc) => {
            const oldLikeCount = doc.data().likeCount;
            const newLikeCount = oldLikeCount + 1;
            return db
                .collection('posts')
                .doc(postId)
                .update({
                    likeCount: newLikeCount
                });
        })
        .then(() => {
            const like = {
                userHandle: req.user.userHandle,
                postId: postId,
                likedAt: new Date().toISOString()
            };

            return db
                    .collection('likes')
                    .add(like);
        })
        .then(() => {
            return res.json({message: `Successfully liked ${postId}`});
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            return res.status(500).json({error: err});
        });
}
```

In this code, the res.status(404).json() gets hit AND the rest of the .then chains DON'T execute, which is perfect. But this code uses too many reads and writes as well as it's unable to update a document more than 1 time per second.

Here is the new code that has the bug:

```
exports.likepost = (req, res) => {

    const postId = req.body.postId;

    db
        .collection('likes')
        .where('postId', '==', postId)
        .where('userHandle', '==', req.user.userHandle)
        .get()
        .then((likeDoc) => {
            if(!likeDoc.empty){
                return res.status(401).json({'Error': `${req.user.userHandle} already liked this post`});
            } // It should stop here but it is not.... the code returns the 401 status and the error message so it hits this code, but it doesn't stop the chain
            else{
                // Update count
                const postRef = db
                    .collection('posts')
                    .doc(postId);
                postRef.update({likeCount: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)});
            }
        })
        .then(() => {
            const like = {
                userHandle: req.user.userHandle,
                postId: postId,
                likedAt: new Date().toISOString()
            };
            return db
                    .collection('likes')
                    .add(like);
        })
        .then(() => {
            return res.json({message: `Successfully liked ${postId}`});
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.error(err);
            return res.status(500).json({error: err});
        });
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that stacking 3 or 4 `then()` in sequence of one another is a best practice. If you changed your code to include the `then()` inside one another, this kind of unexpected behaviour would be mitigated. Here is what your code could look like if you follow this approach(on your new code version):

```
exports.likepost = (req, res) => {
    const postId = req.body.postId;
    db.collection('likes')
      .where('postId', '==', postId)
      .where('userHandle', '==', req.user.userHandle)
      .get()
      .then((likeDoc) => {
          if(!likeDoc.empty){
              return res.status(401).json({'Error': `${req.user.userHandle} already liked this post`});
          } 
          else{
              const postRef = db.collection('posts').doc(postId);
              postRef.update({likeCount: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)}).then({
                  const like = {
                      userHandle: req.user.userHandle,
                      postId: postId,
                      likedAt: new Date().toISOString()
                  };
                  db.collection('likes').add(like).then({
                      return res.json({message: `Successfully liked ${postId}`});
                  });
              });
          }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
            console.error(err);
            return res.status(500).json({error: err});
      });
}
```

Hope this helps.